# jcenter.bitrary library support-v4/26.1.0 not accessible || Android Build || Ionic Build || error

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Please, someone can check this and tell me that where it has been moved. The problem started today when building an ionic app.

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.jar

Comment: Try with this https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.aar

Comment: I am also having this problem, the closest I can find is [this](https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.aar) but it's a .aar instead the needed .jar file. The jar appears to have been removed from both jcenter and google's maven.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue today - scratched my head for a while before I realized the package was missing. No other reports on it than your post, too so... yeeha.

What worked for me just now was removing jcenter from the gradle buildscript and allprojects repositories and adding three others. now it looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }

compatibility
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
}
```

I also told android studio not to try and update gradle - after that it worked. All this was really specific - so I don't know which one of the things I did was actually the solution. Hope this helps anyway ;)

Comment: I solved this issue doing:
```allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() <---added this line
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
}```